# Windows 10 says the monitor supports touch input while it doesn't

Tags: windows-10

Recently, I noticed that in my PC having Windows 10 Pro, in the Control Panel it is written **Pen and Touch : Touch support with 20 touch points**. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzpKL.png)

But, after checking the monitor many times I found that it is not registering any touch input. So, why is the OS telling that the monitor supports upto 20 touch points?

Comment: Which display adapter and which monitor?

Comment: Display adapter is **Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500**, monitor type is **Generic PnP Monitor**. The monitor company is **Compaq**. The monitor is much older than the CPU.

Comment: "Generic PnP Monitor" means the monitor wasn't identified. What is its true model?

Comment: I don't actually know that, because as I had told, it is a comparatively old monitor. I can only say that the company is **Compaq** and it uses VGA port for graphics signals. Is that the cause due to which the OS is providing wrong information about the monitor?

Comment: There is a good chance that this is indeed the reason. Try to identify it using [this article](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c00794706).

Comment: I recently bought a new monitor, whose model is Dell SE2219HX. But, still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows might believe you have touch support because you have some
touch device or trackpad or stylus.
The touch device does not have to be the screen.
On some Dell computers Windows misidentifies the hardware and enables touch when
there is none, especially on laptops, perhaps because it misidentifies the laptop
model.

If your computer is not touch capable on any device, it would be best to disregard
this false indication.

If ignoring this problem is not a solution, because other applications may by mistake
show a wrong interface specialized for touch devices, a false touch screen
can be disabled:

- Start Device Manager
- Open "Human Interface Devices"
- For all HID-compliant touch screens (there may be more than one listed),
  in the Action tab select Disable device.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I don't have any kind of touch-based devices installed.

Comment: Recently, I updated the monitor driver and after the problem seems to have been solved. Now the settings page shows `No touch input available for this display`.

Comment: Still, I am marking this as answer because many of my friends had faced the same issue just because of touchpads connected to their systems.

Comment: I don't really make the distinction here between Windows and the device driver for misidentifying the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

there is also an application called spacedesk which can use your phone/tablet as a secondary monitor it can cause Touch support with 20 touch points Because u actually have it when using phone/tablet as a secondary monitor

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed a 3rd party driver that causes your desktop OS to be identified as a touch-enabled device. One of such drivers / applications is e.g. spacedesk which allows you to use your smartphone or tablet as a secondary monitor. Only after uninstalling it entirely, other applications were able to tell properly that my Windows machine has no touch-support.